# HTML escape chars

Tags: html, escaping

How do I use `>` and `<` in HTML?

Here is an example:

```
<h2>To put big text in HTML, use <h1>Your text</h1></h2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use html entities:

```
&lt;
&gt;
```

```html
<h1>&lt;some text&gt;</h1>
```

You can find the complete list of html entities here:
https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref